# Cassandra/CQL object mapping library comparison

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I am looking for libraries that supports CQL object mapping, and I came across DataStax Java driver families and Achilles. I would like to know their differences in terms of CRUD support down to the details.

**Edit**

1. Keyspace and table creation that supports clustering or composite key.
2. Supports (flexible) select API
3. Which one has better performance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is various ways to do query or create column family from java .
But datastax java driver  gives you better performance in terms of time in read and write query.

You can also use spring for orm . It will gives you better ways to do a query .